# java EE installation and setup

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I need to develop a simple email client in Java. I will be using JavaMail APIs of Java EE. I installed NetBeans that supports Java EE from this site:

http://netbeans.org/downloads/

If I select the option of creating a Java EE application while creating project, I dont get the drag-n-drop feature of creating GUI with swings. And if I select Java Desktop Application I get the GUI building features but then Java EE libraries are not available. How can I use these two simultaneously?

Also, the NetBeans installer seems to install Java EE SDK. In which folder is this SDK installed?

I have experience of using Java SE but I am totally new to Java EE. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just the mail API, get the javamail.jar and add it to your classpath. I'd also recommend [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/), which is a nice simplification of Java Mail API

Answer (score 1):

Java EE are just libraries (no additional language constructs and support), the best solution for you is to download somewhere *.jar you need and add it to your libraries (directly or via maven).